# I am trying to implement fft2 (scipy) function for the two time matrix Fourier Transform and struggling with the extraction of relevant frequency

Tags: python, scipy, fft

here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.integrate as scint
from scipy.linalg import expm

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# =============================================================================
# =============================================================================
# # # 
# =============================================================================
# =============================================================================
def g_k(V,kx,ky):
    g1 = V * (2.0 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3.0)*kx/2.0) * np.cos(ky/2.0) + np.cos(ky) )
    g2 = V * 1j * (-2.0 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3.0)*kx/2.0) * np.sin(ky/2.0) + np.sin(ky) )
    return g1 + g2

def P_sigma_pump_t(t_pump, t, sigma_pump):
    pst = np.exp( - (t-t_pump)**2 / (2*sigma_pump*sigma_pump))
    return pst
def S_probe_shape(t, s_probe, tpr):
    return np.exp(-0.5*(t-tpr)**2/s_probe**2)
    
    
    
def g_k_t(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky):
    elipticity = 0
    kx_new = kx - Amax * P_sigma_pump_t(t_pump, t, sigma_pump) * (np.sin(omega*t))
    ky_new = ky - elipticity * Amax * P_sigma_pump_t(t_pump, t, sigma_pump) * (np.cos(omega*t))
    
    #g1 = V * (2 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3)*kx_new/2) * np.cos(ky_new/2) + np.cos(ky_new) )
    #g2 = V * 1j * (-2 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3)*kx_new/2) * np.sin(ky_new/2) + np.sin(ky_new) )
    #return g1 + g2
    
    return g_k(V,kx_new,ky_new)

# def pump_pulse():
#     A_t = Amax * P_sigma_pump_t * (np.sin(omega*t))
    
def eps1_k(V, kx, ky):
    #e1 = ( ( 2 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3)*kx/2) * np.cos(ky/2) + np.cos(ky)))**2
    #e2 = ( ( -2 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3)*kx/2) * np.sin(ky/2) + np.sin(ky)))**2
    #return V * ( e1 + e2 )

    return np.sqrt( g_k(V,kx,ky) * g_k(V,kx,ky).conj() )


def eps2_k(V, kx, ky):
    #e1 = ( ( 2 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3)*kx/2) * np.cos(ky/2) + np.cos(ky)))**2
    #e2 = ( ( -2 * np.cos(np.sqrt(3)*kx/2) * np.sin(ky/2) + np.sin(ky)))**2
    #return -V * ( e1 + e2 )
    return -1.0 * np.sqrt( g_k(V,kx,ky) * g_k(V,kx,ky).conj() )


def hamiltonian(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx, ky, driving_on):
    
    ham = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=complex)
    
    if driving_on == True:
        ham[0,0] = 0
        ham[0,1] = g_k_t(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky)
        ham[1,0] = (g_k_t(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky)).conj()
        ham[1,1] = 0
        return ham 
    else:
        ham[0,0] = 0
        ham[0,1] = g_k(V,kx,ky)
        ham[1,0] = (g_k(V,kx,ky)).conj()
        ham[1,1] = 0  
        return ham

def time_evo_op(V, t_pump, sigma_pump, tp, t, delta_t, Amax, omega, kx, ky, driving_on = True):
    N_time_steps = int((t - tp)/delta_t)
    #uu = np.ones((2,2), dtype=complex)
    time = 0
    uu = expm(-1j * time * hamiltonian(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, time, Amax, omega, kx,ky,driving_on = False)) 
    result = [] 
    result.append(uu) 
    for it in range(N_time_steps):
        # time = t - it * delta_t / 2.0
        time = t - it * delta_t / 2.0
        HH = hamiltonian(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, time, Amax, omega, kx,ky,driving_on = True)
        
        uu = uu * expm(-1j * HH * delta_t)
        result.append(uu)
        print("here--->uu" ,uu)
    return result

def band_oc_mat(V, kx, ky, T_temp, mu):
    NN = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=complex)
    kb = 1
    beta = 1.0 / (kb*T_temp)
    NN[0,0] = 1.0 / ( np.exp( beta * ( eps1_k(V, kx, ky) - mu)) + 1.0)
    NN[0,1] = 0
    NN[1,0] = 0
    NN[1,1] = 1.0 / ( np.exp( beta * ( eps2_k(V, kx, ky) - mu)) + 1.0)
    return NN

def rot_mat(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky):
    HH_t_ind = hamiltonian(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky,driving_on = False)
    Eval, Evec = np.linalg.eigh(HH_t_ind)
    return Evec

def G_lesr_k(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky, T_temp, mu):
    N_R =  band_oc_mat(V,kx,ky,T_temp,mu) * ( rot_mat(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky) ).T
    R_i_N = rot_mat(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky) * 1j * N_R
    
    return R_i_N

def G_lesr_k_t_tprime(V,t_pump, sigma_pump,tp, t, delta_t, Amax, omega, kx,ky, T_temp, mu) :
    #Utp = time_evo_op(V,t_pump, sigma_pump,0, tp, Amax, omega, kx,ky)
    Ut = time_evo_op(V,t_pump, sigma_pump,0, t, delta_t, Amax, omega, kx,ky)
    print(Ut)
    # print("here----->Ut",Ut)
    
    index_time2 = abs(int((t - tp) * 2/delta_t))
    print("here----->Ut",index_time2)
    G_t1_t2 = G_lesr_k(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky, T_temp, mu) * Ut[index_time2]
    result_t1_t2 = Ut[-1].T * G_t1_t2 
    
    # for time1:
    #     for time2:
    #         G_t1_t2 = G_lesr_k * Ut[index_time2]
    #     result_t1_t2 = Ut[index_time1] * G_t1_t2 
    
    #G_Utp = G_lesr_k(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, t, Amax, omega, kx,ky, T_temp, mu) * Utp
    #Ut_G = Ut.T * G_Utp
    #return Ut_G
    return result_t1_t2 
    




# =============================================================================
# parameters
# =============================================================================
e = h_bar = c = 1
V = 2.8
T_temp_in_K = 116/V

# Time parameters

t_probe = 1.0
t_pump = 1.0
delay_time = t_probe - t_pump
# time_steps = 0.5

# material parameters
a_cc = 1.42

mu = 0.5/V
E_D = -0.5

#simulation parameters
Omega_pump = 1.5

Osci_period = 2.58
sigma_pump = 20
A_max = 0.0
E_max = Omega_pump*A_max
sigma_probe = 2


delta_t = 0.1
# =============================================================================
# # 
# =============================================================================

num_kpts = 30
# KX = np.linspace(4*np.pi/(3*np.sqrt(3)) - 4, 4*np.pi/(3*np.sqrt(3)) + 4, num_kpts)
KX = np.linspace(-1.6, 4.0, num_kpts)
ky = 0
tmax = 5

t_prime = tmax
tt = tmax

N_time_steps = int(tt/delta_t)


UUV = []
for ii in range(len(KX)):
    kx = KX[ii]
    U_time_evo = time_evo_op(V, t_pump, sigma_pump, 0, tt, delta_t, A_max, Omega_pump, kx, ky, driving_on = True)
    UUV.append(U_time_evo)
  
I_k_t_for_fft2 = []
for ii in range(len(KX)):
    kx = KX[ii]
    Mat_two_time = np.zeros((N_time_steps,N_time_steps),dtype = complex)
    for ti in range(N_time_steps):
        t1 = delta_t + ti*delta_t
        U_time_evo2 = UUV[ii][ti]
        
        for tj in range(N_time_steps):
            t2 = delta_t + tj*delta_t
            print("time(t1 = %s,t2 = %s)(K:%s):(%s,%s)"%(tt,t_prime,kx,t1,t2))
            U_time_evo1 = UUV[ii][tj]
            
            G_k = G_lesr_k(V,t_pump, sigma_pump, tt, A_max, Omega_pump, kx,ky, T_temp_in_K, mu)
            GLess_k_t_tprime = U_time_evo2.T * G_k * U_time_evo1
            G_aa_bb = GLess_k_t_tprime[0,0] + GLess_k_t_tprime[1,1]
            Mat_two_time[ti,tj] = S_probe_shape(t1, sigma_probe, t_probe)* S_probe_shape(t2, sigma_probe, t_probe) * G_aa_bb
        
    I_k_t_for_fft2.append(Mat_two_time)
from scipy.fft import fft2, fftfreq
fft2_Mat_for_fft_all = fft2(I_k_t_for_fft2)
BandStructure = [] 
for ii in range(len(KX)):
    Mat_for_fft = I_k_t_for_fft2[ii]
    fft2_Mat_for_fft = fft2(Mat_for_fft)
    # sfplot = plt.imshow(np.log(abs(fft2_Mat_for_fft)),cmap='gnuplot',interpolation='none')
    # plt.show()
    # plt.close()
    Diag_Vec = np.diagonal(fft2_Mat_for_fft)
    # Diag_Vec = fft2_Mat_for_fft[:,2]
    BandStructure.append(Diag_Vec)
    print("Diag_Vec === ",Diag_Vec)
    



BandStructure2 = (np.array(BandStructure).imag).T
# freq_y = fftfreq(BandStructure2.shape[0])
# # freq_x = fftfreq(KX.shape[0])
# freq_x = fftfreq(num_kpts, d=1/(2*np.pi*num_kpts))
# freq_x, freq_y = np.meshgrid(freq_x, freq_y)
# freq = np.sqrt(freq_x**2 + freq_y**2)

BandStructure2 = np.roll(BandStructure2,1,axis=1)

a,b = BandStructure2.shape
sfplot1 = plt.imshow(np.log(abs(BandStructure2)),aspect=b/a,cmap='gnuplot',interpolation='none')#)#, aspect=4,interpolation="none")
# #plt.plot(test_fT[0])
# plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.colorbar(sfplot1,location='right', anchor=(0, 0.3), shrink=0.7)     
# plt.contour(freq, levels=[1], colors='w')
```

here, I_k_t_for_fft2 is a list of matrices for each Kx value, and in the end, I want to plot the frequency vs Kx for the band structure. after implying fft2 over each two time matrices in I_k_t_for_fft2 I'm confused to extract the relevant frequencies for each kx value.

I tried just taking the diagonal entry of each two-time matrix in the I_k_t_for_fft2 list. I'm not sure whether it's the correct extraction.